# adding unique key value pair in HashMap without overwriting existing data

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to add multiple key value pair in hash map using for loop but It only stores 1 key value pair per iteration and when I try to print all the data inside the hash map the key value is separated by curly braces, why is that?

Key = String

Value = Integer

```
public void foo(int j){
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < j+1; i++) {
            if(i == this.counter){
                //System.out.println(this.thing + " " + this.counter);
                map.put(this.thing, this.counter);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

actual output:

```
{pencil=2}
{paper=3}
{pen=1}
```

I thought the output should be like this
expected output:

```
{"pencil=2", "paper=3", "pen=1"}
```

I'm not getting the expected output so I cant arrange the hash map by value in descending order. How to fix this?

EDIT:

Is it possible to put the the actual output into another hash map then I will sort the new hash map by value in descending order? if it is possible, please show me how. Many thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to get output like that from any JRE `Map` implementation. Is it your own class? Also, no implementation will sort a `Map` by values/ You could have a `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>>` though

Answer (score 0):

I learned that it is possible to store the actual output into another hash map using for loop and when I printed the new hash map, I got the expected output. I also used the new hash map to sort the key-value pairs in descending order because the new hash map has the expected output and I can manipulate that easier than the old hash map.

Comment: Of what type is 'map' in your posted code?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that I didn't include the initialization of the map. Its a hash map. thank u for pointing that out.

Comment: The problem is that you can't possibly get the output you call the "actual output" - for two reasons - a. JRE maps don't print like that and b. that map could only ever have (at most) one entry since the key doesn't change in the loop